# async class method not working in node.js 7.6 +

Tags: node.js

How to specify async class method in node.js 7.6 +

The following ways are breaking :

```
class A{

   async abc(){
    // 
    return 'abc';
   }

}
```

and

```
class A{

   async function abc(){
    // 
    return 'abc';
   }

}
```

GIves Error

```
  async abc(ll){
          ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
```

To start app.
node src/main.js

The package.json and the Dependencies  are as follows.

```
{
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "on",
  "main": "src/mn.js",
  "dependencies": {

    "underscore":"*",
    "moment": "2.12.0",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.3",

    "url": "0.11.0",
    "lodash":"4.11.1",
    "request": "*",
    "shelljs": "0.5.3",
    "busboy": "0.2.13",
    "bluebird": "3.3.1",
    "q": "1.4.1",

    "nodemailer": "2.2.*",

    "mongojs": "2.3.0",
    "mongodb": "2.1.7",
    "generic-pool": "2.4.0",
    "priorityqueuejs": "1.0.0",
    "object-path": "0.9.2",
    "merge": "1.2.0",

    "amqp": "0.2.4",
    "request": "2.69.0",
    "kafka": "0.2.3",
    "mongo-oplog":"1.0.1",
    "websocket":"1.0.23",
    "ws":"1.1.1",

    "node-sass": "3.8.*",
    "jsonwebtoken": "5.7.0",

    "winston": "1.1.1",
    "winston-logstash": "0.2.11",

    "xlsx": "0.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  },
  "scripts": {
  }
}
```

Note : i also have Blueird as some part of my code is using bluebird, is that fine /

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting any error?

Comment: gives :     SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: what command are you using to start your app? can you show your *package.json*?

Comment: also added package.json, it also uses bluebird for some legacy code .. is that ok

Comment: I guess so, have you tried using `node --harmony src/main.js` instead of `node src/main.js`?

Comment: I retried changing version,, working fine now.. THanks !!!